# If Else Loop not working in Powershell Inventory Script

Tags: powershell

Note – I am not a coding expert so please be gentle  Any assistance/guidance much appreciated

Issue is that my pieced together Powershell script is not working as correctly. I am guessing it will take a coding guru two seconds to help resolve.
The basics of the script is that it performs a basic audit of a list of servers from a text file and outputs the results to a csv. For each server it will test WMI connection and if successful will collect columns of data i.e Name, IP Address, Uptime etc. If WMI connection fails then it should just log a few columns of data i.e. WMI Result, Ping Result etc All results should be piped to the same single output csv

The script works perfectly if the first server in the list’s WMI connection succeeds. All 16 x columns of csv output file are populated for every server in list.
[WorkingExample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YuLez.png)

If the first server in the list’s WMI connection fails then the output fails. Only 4 x columns of csv output file are populated for every server in list.
[FailingExample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4bLdc.png)

Hopefully the screenshots of the output csv's help

Powershell Code below

```bsh
<#

.DESCRIPTION - Auditing Script - Construction Phase !!!

- Create folder called 'Audit' under C:\Temp
- Create text file called 'Servers.txt' and place in newly created C:\Temp\Audit folder
- Servers.txt should contain a list of server names you wish to audit\target

.Author MCD

#>

        ########## Output Folder ##########
        $outputFolderName = 'Audit ' + $(Get-Date -f dd-MM-yyyy)
        $outputpath = "C:\temp\Audit\$outputFolderName"
        If(!(test-path $outputpath))
            {
              New-Item -ItemType Directory -Force -Path $outputpath | out-null
            }
                
        ########## Prompt 1 ##########
        Add-Type -AssemblyName Microsoft.VisualBasic
        $ClientName = [Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction]::InputBox('Please enter Client\Customer name i.e. Contoso Ltd', 'User')
        Start-Sleep -s 2

        #Manual Input File Location
        $computers = Get-Content -path c:\temp\audit\Servers.txt
                
        ########## Create an Empty Array ##########
        $report = @()

        ########## Main Start ##########
        Foreach ($Computer in $Computers)
{
    
        ########## WMI/Ping Test ##########
        $wmi = gwmi win32_bios -ComputerName $computer -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
        $Ping = Test-Connection -ComputerName $computer -Quiet -count 2
        
        ########## Main If Else Loop ##########
        if ($wmi)
    {
        $WMIResult = 'Server IS Contactable' 
                
        ########## HW/Serial No/Bios ##########
        $Bios = Get-WmiObject -Class win32_bios -ComputerName $Computer
        $systemBios = $Bios.serialnumber
        $Hardware = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_computerSystem -ComputerName $Computer
                        
        ########## OS Version/Last Reboot ##########
        $OS = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_OperatingSystem -ComputerName $Computer
        $lastBoot = $OS.ConvertToDateTime($OS.LastBootUpTime)
        $uptimeDays = ((get-date) - ($os.ConvertToDateTime($os.lastbootuptime))).Days
        
        ########## Network Info ##########
        $Networks = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration -ComputerName $Computer | Where-Object {$_.IPEnabled}
        $IPAddress  = ($Networks.IpAddress | where {$_ -notmatch ":"}) -join "`n"
        $MACAddress  = ($Networks.MACAddress) -join "`n"
        $IpSubnet  = ($Networks.IpSubnet | ? { $_ -match '\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}' }) -join "`n"
        $DefaultGateway = ($Networks.DefaultIPGateway) -join "`n"
        
        ########## LastLogon/Created ##########
        $LastLogonDate = Get-ADComputer $computer -Properties * | select -ExpandProperty LastLogonDate 
        $Created = Get-ADComputer $computer -Properties * | select -ExpandProperty Created 
        
            ########## OUTPUT ##########
            $tempreport  = New-Object -TypeName PSObject
            $tempreport | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name ServerName -Value $Computer.ToUpper()
            $tempreport | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Client_Customer -Value $ClientName.ToUpper()
            $tempreport | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name WMI_Connection -Value $WMIResult
            $tempreport | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Pingable -Value $Ping
            $tempreport | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Manufacturer -Value $Hardware.Manufacturer
            $tempreport | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Model -Value $Hardware.Model
            $tempreport | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Operating_System -Value $OS.Caption
            $tempreport | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name IP_Address -Value $IPAddress
            $tempreport | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Default_Gateway -Value $DefaultGateway
            $tempreport | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name MAC_Address -Value $MACAddress
            $tempreport | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name IpSubnet -Value $IpSubnet
            $tempreport | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Last_ReBoot -Value $lastboot
            $tempreport | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Uptime_Days -Value $uptimeDays
            $tempreport | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Last_Logon -Value $LastLogonDate
            $tempreport | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Created -Value $Created
            $tempreport | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Serial_Number -Value $systemBios
            
            $report += $tempreport
                
    }   else    {
    
        $WMIResult = 'Server NOT Contactable'
                
            $tempreport = New-Object PSObject  
            $tempreport | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name ServerName -Value $Computer.ToUpper()
            $tempreport | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Client_Customer -Value $ClientName.ToUpper()
            $tempreport | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name WMI_Connection -Value $WMIResult
            $tempreport | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Pingable -Value $Ping
            
            $report += $tempreport  
       
                }
}

        ########## EXPORT TO CSV ##########
        $CSVFileName = $ClientName + ' Server Inventory ' + $(Get-Date -f dd-MM-yyyy) + '.csv'
        $report | Export-Csv "$outputpath\$CSVFileName" -NoTypeInformation


<#

.END

#>
```

Comment: please, fix your code formatting. right now it is nearly indecipherable ... [*grin*]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that the two objects you are creating don't contain the same properties. Arrays will report the information based on the properties in the first object. So if the first object fails, then all the others will report back the same four properties when the array is output.

My suggestion for dealing with this in the most simple way is to add the additional properties to the failing object, setting the values as `$null`. This should see that your CSV receives all the properties as intended.

```bsh
<#
.DESCRIPTION - Auditing Script - Construction Phase !!!
- Create folder called 'Audit' under C:\Temp
- Create text file called 'Servers.txt' and place in newly created C:\Temp\Audit folder
- Servers.txt should contain a list of server names you wish to audit\target
.Author MCD
#>

########## Output Folder ##########
$outputFolderName = 'Audit ' + $(Get-Date -f dd-MM-yyyy)
$outputpath = "C:\temp\Audit\$outputFolderName"
If(!(test-path $outputpath)) {
    New-Item -ItemType Directory -Force -Path $outputpath | out-null
}
                
########## Prompt 1 ##########
Add-Type -AssemblyName Microsoft.VisualBasic
$ClientName = [Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction]::InputBox('Please enter Client\Customer name i.e. Contoso Ltd', 'User')
Start-Sleep -s 2

#Manual Input File Location
$computers = Get-Content -path c:\temp\audit\Servers.txt
                
########## Create an Empty Array ##########
$report = @()

########## Main Start ##########
Foreach ($Computer in $Computers) {
    
    ########## WMI/Ping Test ##########
    $wmi = gwmi win32_bios -ComputerName $computer -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    $Ping = Test-Connection -ComputerName $computer -Quiet -count 2
        
    ########## Main If Else Loop ##########
    if ($wmi) {
        $WMIResult = 'Server IS Contactable' 
                
        ########## HW/Serial No/Bios ##########
        $Bios = Get-WmiObject -Class win32_bios -ComputerName $Computer
        $systemBios = $Bios.serialnumber
        $Hardware = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_computerSystem -ComputerName $Computer
                        
        ########## OS Version/Last Reboot ##########
        $OS = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_OperatingSystem -ComputerName $Computer
        $lastBoot = $OS.ConvertToDateTime($OS.LastBootUpTime)
        $uptimeDays = ((get-date) - ($os.ConvertToDateTime($os.lastbootuptime))).Days
        
        ########## Network Info ##########
        $Networks = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration -ComputerName $Computer | Where-Object {$_.IPEnabled}
        $IPAddress  = ($Networks.IpAddress | where {$_ -notmatch ":"}) -join "`n"
        $MACAddress  = ($Networks.MACAddress) -join "`n"
        $IpSubnet  = ($Networks.IpSubnet | ? { $_ -match '\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}' }) -join "`n"
        $DefaultGateway = ($Networks.DefaultIPGateway) -join "`n"
        
        ########## LastLogon/Created ##########
        $LastLogonDate = Get-ADComputer $computer -Properties * | select -ExpandProperty LastLogonDate 
        $Created = Get-ADComputer $computer -Properties * | select -ExpandProperty Created 
        
        ########## OUTPUT ##########
        $tempreport  = New-Object -TypeName PSObject
        $tempreport | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name ServerName -Value $Computer.ToUpper()
        $tempreport | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Client_Customer -Value $ClientName.ToUpper()
        $tempreport | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name WMI_Connection -Value $WMIResult
        $tempreport | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Pingable -Value $Ping
        $tempreport | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Manufacturer -Value $Hardware.Manufacturer
        $tempreport | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Model -Value $Hardware.Model
        $tempreport | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Operating_System -Value $OS.Caption
        $tempreport | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name IP_Address -Value $IPAddress
        $tempreport | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Default_Gateway -Value $DefaultGateway
        $tempreport | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name MAC_Address -Value $MACAddress
        $tempreport | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name IpSubnet -Value $IpSubnet
        $tempreport | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Last_ReBoot -Value $lastboot
        $tempreport | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Uptime_Days -Value $uptimeDays
        $tempreport | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Last_Logon -Value $LastLogonDate
        $tempreport | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Created -Value $Created
        $tempreport | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Serial_Number -Value $systemBios
            
        $report += $tempreport
                
    }
    else {
    
        $WMIResult = 'Server NOT Contactable'
                
        $tempreport = New-Object PSObject  
        $tempreport | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name ServerName -Value $Computer.ToUpper()
        $tempreport | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Client_Customer -Value $ClientName.ToUpper()
        $tempreport | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name WMI_Connection -Value $WMIResult
        $tempreport | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Pingable -Value $Ping
        $tempreport | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Manufacturer -Value $null
        $tempreport | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Model -Value $null
        $tempreport | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Operating_System -Value $null
        $tempreport | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name IP_Address -Value $null
        $tempreport | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Default_Gateway -Value $null
        $tempreport | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name MAC_Address -Value $null
        $tempreport | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name IpSubnet -Value $null
        $tempreport | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Last_ReBoot -Value $null
        $tempreport | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Uptime_Days -Value $null
        $tempreport | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Last_Logon -Value $null
        $tempreport | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Created -Value $null
        $tempreport | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Serial_Number -Value $null
            
        $report += $tempreport  
    }
}

########## EXPORT TO CSV ##########
$CSVFileName = $ClientName + ' Server Inventory ' + $(Get-Date -f dd-MM-yyyy) + '.csv'
$report | Export-Csv "$outputpath\$CSVFileName" -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: Awesome! Works a treat. Thank you for your help Ash. Much appreciated